# How to fix design view errors e.g. "System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException"?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you go about debugging errors in the design view? For some reason only one form has issues opening up in design view. I would like to at the very least see the full error message but I'm not sure how to find that. All I have to debug are these two messages:

MessageBox error:

[image: MessageBox error]

DesignView error:

[image: DesignView error]

Comment: Can you show the config that’s failing? The second message suggests some kind of malformed URL

Comment: [Set up the project for design-time debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/walkthrough-debugging-custom-windows-forms-controls-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#set-up-the-project-for-design-time-debugging)

Comment: @stuartd it's a connection string in App.config. The url within the connection string is `localhost`. The program works fine in runtime but I'm getting issues in design view.

@RezaAghaei Thank you, I will look into debugging it this way.

Comment: `localhost` is not a valid URL..

Comment: @stuartd I mean the connection string is valid and allows the application to connect to the db during runtime.  Through trial error I was able to find where the issues was but it seems silly that code that is valid during runtime is not valid during design.